# Flutter toolbar overlapping below status bar

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am wondering where the top edge of application starts in flutter. Look at the following hello world app:

[image]

The debug banner has gone below the status bar, which indicates that the top edge of my application starts from the edge of the screen. However, the application's `AppBar` has been place right after the status bar. This insconsistency is confusing me! Is the small part of application overlapped under status bar part of my application or not? Why is the `AppBar` not under status bar? How can I decide how my app should overlap with status bar? And what's the best practice here? Is overlapping the application header with status bar a good practice?

Answer (score 173, accepted):

Actually, the appbar *is* partially under the status bar. It just has an internal padding to handle it correctly

This is very clear when you remove the appbar :

```
Scaffold(
  body: Text("Hello"),
)
```

In this situation, it will render "Hello" under the status bar.

You can fix this by wrapping your body into a `SafeArea` :

```
Scaffold(
  body: SafeArea(
    child: Text("Hello"),
  ),
),
```

Comment: Sorry but this didn't answer the question. I just want the 'slow mode' banner goes under the status bar.

Comment: @Chandler this answer is a "The problem you're trying to solve is not a problem." It is the desired behavior, and there are no reasons for it to change.

Comment: Safe area should be the default imo (not require specifying) but I guess with notches and stuff now things are different

Comment: @DanielWilson That's the default. Appbar includes such padding.

Comment: set `extendBodyBehindAppbar` to true in `Scaffold`