# Webview Flutter font size is too small in IOS

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I have html code that I need to render in webview to display HTML text editor styled content. The one and only option is to use webview. So, I implemented my API to send response particular `<div>` element and displayed it using official [flutter webview](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter). Android its displaying correctly and IOS font sized is very small(can't even read). What I am doing wrong?

Relevant code snippet:

```
var contentBase64 = base64Encode(const Utf8Encoder()
      .convert(
      """<html>
          <body style='"margin: 0; padding: 0;'>
            <div>
              $htmlString //my html code snippet coming from API
            </div>
          </body>
        </html>"""));

//.....
WebView(
    initialUrl: 'data:text/html;base64,$contentBase64',
//  gestureRecognizers: Set()..add(Factory<VerticalDragGestureRecognizer>(()=>VerticalDragGestureRecognizer())),
),
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The reason is, you only wrapped with `html` element. You have to specify `meta` tag to responsive in IOS devices. To do that you also have to add `head` element as below:

```
  var contentBase64 = base64Encode(const Utf8Encoder()
  .convert(
  """<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"></head>
      <body style='"margin: 0; padding: 0;'>
        <div>
          $htmlString
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>"""));
```

In **my opinion**:

Android is smart enough to identify html code without `<meta>` with viewport, but IOS does not. You have to explicitly set viewport to mobile device, like you make webapp responsive to mobile devices.

It's better to wrap `<!DOCTYPE html>` annotation to render correctly.

This is what you need exactly to your code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"></head><!--rest of your html-->
```

Comment: Good answer! I had to do this running on a Pixel 5, but your solution worked. The only thing is that my <h1> text overlays the device toolbar at the top, and a couple of the letters are masked out by the camera lens. Weird... lol

Comment: Above I meant stausbar, not toolbar. But I found a solution at
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51673434/flutter-toolbar-overlapping-below-status-bar

Comment: Good answer. Thanks